# Should i repeat person name in alt text of <img> if name is already in source under image?

Tags: html, xhtml, accessibility, screen-readers

if I'm already having person name under/over image then should i use same name in ALT text?

[alt text http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/227/6990285751.jpg](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/227/6990285751.jpg)

```
<p><img width="125" height="157" alt="George Washington" 
src="media/gw.jpg"><span>George Washington</span><p>


<p><span>George Washington</span>
<img width="125" height="157" alt="George Washington" src="media/gw.jpg"><p>
```

Should i repeat `<span>` in `alt` in both condition ? image has no link.

Comment: No need for a separate answer, but I'd like to point out jensgram's comment to kervin's answer, since it reflects perfectly my own opinion.

Comment: @Boldewyn Thank you. I did, however, post a separate answer :)

Comment: @jensgram: I meant, no need for another answer from *me*. So, I don't object ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes.

ALT Text is important for screen readers and such.  Text 'nearby' to an image doesn't have much meaning to these programs.

Some more information from [W3C](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/altAttribute) on the subject.

Comment: but screen reader will repeat same name in ALT="person name" and <p>person name?

Comment: The screen reader can let the user know that there is a image on the page and it pertains to 'whatever is in ALT'.  So the user know has a little knowledge about what they're missing.  It will then continue with the page.  Without that ALT, the user would never know what was in the image.

Comment: +1 Agree. However, I would use the `ALT` attribute to provide a *description* of the image, e.g. "Portrait of George Washington, oil on canvas, circa 1790".

Comment: I disagree. And so does the W3C:

"Do not specify irrelevant alternate text when including images intended to format a page, for instance, alt=”red ball” would be inappropriate for an image that adds a red ball for decorating a heading or paragraph. In such cases, the alternate text should be the empty string (”")."  

"Red Ball" in this case "George Washington"

Comment: @Nils: It *is not* irrelevant in W3C's terms. The image here does matter and is a necessary component to understand the content. The spec refers to cases, where the image is merely decoration.

Comment: @Nils Riedermann "... images intended to format a page ...". This is not the case - at least as far as I understood the question.

Comment: @jensgram: I was up to write exactly this ('...as an description...')  as an answer. Good you pointed it out.

Comment: Updated my answer. I think i got misunderstood. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 5):

**No** ... and **yes**!

- No, I my opinion you should not just *repeat* the text.
- However, you *should* see the `ALT` attribute as an opportunity to provide a (short) *description* of the image, e.g. "Portrait of George Washington, oil on canvas, circa 1790".

It this case the image does *not* only serve as page formatting. Instead, it is an information-carrying element. Users who cannot see the information (e.g. screen readers) should at least have a chance to know what they're missing.

Answer (score 3):

No. Duplicate content is unhelpful. If an image merely illustrates something which already exists in the normal text content, it should have a blank alt attribute

As a useful test, use the Lynx browser to look at the page. If it looks stupid, the alt text is wrong.

Here is how it renders if you duplicate the alt text (copy/pasted from your example):

```
    George Washington George Washington
```

Answer (score 3):

**No.** Alt Text is shown as an **alternative** for the image when it cannot be shown.

Here is an extract from the specification that is quite straight forward:

> - Do not specify irrelevant alternate    text when including images intended
>     to format a page, for instance,
>     alt=”red ball” would be inappropriate 
>     for an image that adds a red ball for 
>     decorating a heading or paragraph. In 
>     such cases, the alternate text should 
>     be the empty string (”"). Authors are 
>     in any case advised to avoid using
>     images to format pages; style sheets
>     should be used instead.
> - Do not specify meaningless alternate    text (e.g., “dummy
>     text”). Not only    will this
>     frustrate users, it will    slow down
>     user agents that must    convert text
>     to speech or braille    output. play
>     terminals, users whose    browsers
>     don’t support forms,    visually
>     impaired users, those who    use
>     speech synthesizers, those who    have
>     configured their graphical user
>     agents not to display images, etc.

**So it says  pretty clear not to repeat.** "Red Ball" in the first case can be replaced by "George Washington".

Here is a good article how to use the alt-attribute properly: [Alt attributes](http://ianpouncey.com/weblog/2010/01/alt-attributes/)

**EDIT**:
Ok i think i got misunderstood. I did not say that he mustn't use an alt-attribute here.

We are talkin about screen readers and accessibilty here, right? I agree the image is important to *us*. But is it to blind people? Or is it just decoration for the text?

Remember the question was wether **to repeat the name in the alt attribute.** And i say "No". When images are not shown, the alt-text is displayed. I'd propably do it this way:

```
<p><img src="george.jpg" alt="Image of " />George Washington</p>
```

The alt-Attribute is the **alternative for when the image is not shown** and not a description (we have `description` for this).

Comment: -1 This question is not about whether to use `ALT` text on "images intended to format a page". The image of George Washington is part of the information on the page and the `ALT` text gives the author an opportunity to *describe* what some viewers do not see.

Comment: I updated my answer and made my point clearer, i hope. Maybe you can remove the downvote now? ;)

Comment: Indeed. (filler to reach 15 chars)

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't hurt -- otherwise the screenreader user might be left to wonder if the image is in fact that of the person whose name comes next.

Answer (score 1):

This info pertains to Jaws for windows but probably applys to other screen readers as well. Always put information in an alt tag. How jaws recognizes graphics is fairly customizable, you can have only graphics with alt tags spoken, graphics recognized by mouse over, title attribute, etc. In general with the default configuration alt tags will be spoken and any other information will be ignored. If an alt tag isn't available then the screen reader will do it's best to read the graphic but this is problamatic.

Comment: but if alt text is not defined in image then screen will read text which is after the image

Answer (score 0):

I am going for alt="" here.

Please check this article that provide a very nice examples:
http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/

Quoting from that article:

---

The alt attribute should typically:

- Be accurate and equivalent in presenting the same content and function of the image.
- Be succinct. This means the correct content (if there is content) and function (if there is a function) of the image should be presented as succinctly as is appropriate. Typically no more than a few words are necessary, though rarely a short sentence or two may be appropriate.
- NOT be redundant or provide the same information as text within the context of the image.
- NOT use the phrases "image of ..." or "graphic of ..." to describe the image. It usually apparent to the user that it is an image. And if the image is conveying content, it is typically not necessary that the user know that it is an image that is conveying the content, as opposed to text. If the fact that an image is a photograph or illustration, etc. is important content, it may be useful to include this in alternative text.